# Smart filter (like webshop) for selection of content possibly using taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm currently working on a website which needs to display paintings. 
The paintings have certain attributes: the year-of-painting/painter/background color/material. To get the best user experience i want to let them navigate, like one would browse a webshop.

I like the one on http://www.debijenkorf.nl/action/ViewParametricSearch-SimpleOfferSearch?SearchTerm=moleskin very much.

Are there modules in drupal which i can use, that give me such a smart filter functionality (maybe with taxonomy?)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's usually referred to as a *facetted search*.

Drupal's most oft-used facet solution is probably a combination of:

- [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api])

  > This module provides a framework for easily creating searches on any entity known to Drupal, using any kind of search engine. For site administrators, it is a great alternative to other search solutions, since it already incorporates facetting support and the ability to use the Views module for displaying search results, filters, etc.
- [Facet API](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi)

  > The Facet API module allows site builders to easily create and manage faceted search interfaces.

The module page for each has links to tutorials/examples; you can make some pretty powerful sites with just those two modules, but there are plenty of add-on modules too to augment/improve the basic functionality.

Be prepared for a bit of a learning curve, it takes a little while to get your head around both of the above modules. Diving in and clicking everything on a dev site to see what happens would be the best initial approach IMO.